# Image upload Laravel 7 VueJS

Tags: laravel, image, vue.js, upload

I want upload image to server and display it in the list. I expect to use the same  function 'addProduct' to store image (title & description were successfull).

Got file is empty message in the backend. I have googled a lot, nothing solved my problem.

Sorry I am not experienced in programming. thanks for help in advance!

```
<!-- Vue JS -->    
<!-- Add Product Modal -->
                            
                                    <div>
                                        <b-modal v-model="addModal" hide-footer title="Add New Product">
                                            <div class="d-block text-center">
                                                <b-form
                                                    @submit.stop.prevent="onSubmit"
                                                    enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                                >
                                                    <b-form-group>
                                                        <b-form-input
                                                            v-model="$v.data.title.$model"
                                                            :state="validateState('title')"
                                                            class="mt-3"
                                                            placeholder="Enter Title"
                                                        ></b-form-input>
                                                        <b-form-invalid-feedback
                                                            >This field is required and must be at least 3
                                                            characters.</b-form-invalid-feedback
                                                        >
                                                    </b-form-group>
                                                    <b-form-group>
                                                        <b-form-textarea
                                                            v-model="$v.data.description.$model"
                                                            :state="validateState('description')"
                                                            class="mt-3"
                                                            debounce="500"
                                                            rows="3"
                                                            max-rows="5"
                                                            placeholder="Enter Description"
                                                        ></b-form-textarea>
                                                        <b-form-invalid-feedback
                                                            >This field is
                                                            required.</b-form-invalid-feedback
                                                        >
                                                    </b-form-group>
                            
                                                    <!-- upload form -->
                                                    <b-form-file
                                                        v-model="data.imageName"
                                                        :state="Boolean(data.imageName)"
                                                        placeholder="Choose a file or drop it here..."
                                                        drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
                                                        v-on:change="onFileChange"
                                                    >
                                                    </b-form-file>
                                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                                        Selected File:
                                                        {{ data.imageName ? data.imageName.name : "" }}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- upload form -->
                            
                                                    <b-button
                                                        type="submit"
                                                        class="mt-3"
                                                        variant="outline-success"
                                                        block
                                                        @click="addProduct"
                                                        :disabled="isAdding"
                                                        :loading="isAdding"
                                                        >{{ isAdding ? "Adding.." : "Add" }}</b-button
                                                    >
                                                    <b-button
                                                        class="mt-3"
                                                        variant="outline-danger"
                                                        block
                                                        @click="addModal = false"
                                                        >Close</b-button
                                                    >
                                                </b-form>
                                            </div>
                                        </b-modal>
                                    </div>
                    export default {
                        mixins: [validationMixin],
                        data() {
                            return {
                                data: {
                                    title: "",
                                    description: "",
                                    imageName: []
                                },
                                dismissSecs: 5,
                                dismissCountDown: 0,
                                filename: "",
                                file: "",
                                success: "",
                                errorMsg: {
                                    status: false,
                                    title: ""
                                },
                                successMsg: {
                                    status: false,
                                    title: ""
                                }
                    },
                    resetForm() {
                                this.data = {
                                    title: "",
                                    description: ""
                                };
                                this.$nextTick(() => {
                                    this.$v.$reset();
                                });
                            },
                            onSubmit() {
                                this.$v.data.$touch();
                                if (this.$v.data.$anyError) {
                                    return;
                                },
                     onFileChange(e) {
                                //console.log(e.target.files[0]);
                                this.filename = "Selected File: " + e.target.files[0].name;
                                this.file = e.target.files[0];
                            },
                            async addProduct() {
                                if (
                                    this.data.title.trim() == "" ||
                                    this.data.description.trim() == "" ||
                                    this.data.title.length < 3
                                )
                                    return console.log("error fill required fields!");
                                const res = await this.callApi(
                                    "post",
                                    "products/create_product",
                                    this.data
                                );
                                if (res.status === 201) {
                                    this.products.unshift(res.data);
                                    this.showAlert("Product added successfully.");
                                    this.addModal = false;
                                    this.data.title = "";
                                    this.data.description = "";
                                    this.data.imageName = [];
                                } else {
                                    if (res.status == 422) {
                                        if (
                                            res.data.errors.title ||
                                            res.data.errors.description ||
                                            res.data.errors.imageName
                                        ) {
                                            console.log(res.data.errors);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        console.log(this.data.imageName);
                                        console.log("Something went wrong.");
                                    }
                                }
                                this.resetForm();
                            },
                    async created() {
                        const res = await this.callApi("get", "products/get_products");
                        if (res.status == 200) {
                            this.products = res.data;
                        } else {
                            console.log("error occured!");
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Axios file

```
                import Axios from "axios"
                
                export default {
                    data() {
                        return {
                
                        }
                    },
                    methods: {
                        async callApi(method, url, dabaObj) {
                            try {
                                return await Axios({
                                    method: method,
                                    url: url,
                                    data: dabaObj
                                });
                
                            } catch (e) {
                                console.log(e.response)
                                return e.response
                            }
                        }
                    },
                
                }
```

Controller AdminController.php

```
            class AdminController extends Controller
            {
                public function addProduct(Request $request)
                {
                    // validate addProduct request
                    $this->validate($request, [
                        'title' => 'required',
                        'description' => 'required'
                    ]);
                    if ($request->hasFile('imageName')) {
                        $upload_path = public_path('upload');
                        $imageName = $request->file('imageName')->getClientOriginalName();
                        $generated_new_name = time() . '.' . $request->file('imageName')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $request->file('imageName')->move($upload_path, $generated_new_name);
                
                        $insert['imageName'] = $imageName;
                        $check = Products::insertGetId($insert);
                
                        return Products::create([
                            'title' => $request->title,
                            'description' => $request->description,
                            // 'imageName' => $request->imageName
                        ]);
                    } else {
                        return 'file is empty!!!';
                    }
                }
```

```
    <-- web php file -->
```

```
        Route::post('products/create_product', 'AdminController@addProduct');
```

[image]

Comment: why you put `imageName: []` like array in `data` object .. are you sent multiple file ?  i think `imageName: ' ' ` it will work

Comment: When I change it to quotation marks then I got the error "[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected File, Array, got String with value ""."

Comment: Unfortunately but still does not pass if statement with condition ($request->hasFile('imageName')[0]).

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($request->file("imageName"));`? I would advise you to send your data as FormData object, rather then a plain JSON. Use `const fd = new FormData()` and then `fd.append('title', this.data.title)`, etc.

Comment: @lyyka [link](https://ibb.co/yNLLFZW) output is NULL. I will try using FormData.

Comment: in `onFileChange(e)` function put this line  `this.data.imageName  = e.target.files[0];`.. then cehck..